# Running docker-compose up -d -build , I got the following error:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

> The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
> services.mysql.networks contains an invalid type, it should be an array, or an object

this is the code:

```
 mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks: 
      -backend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space when you defined the network ;) This would work if the backend network already exists in your system!

```
   mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - backend
```

Comment: I meant you are missing space when you defined the network in the docker-compose.yml, so this `-backend` should be changed to `- backend` In addition, the docker network should be already available in your system, you can do that using https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#usage

Comment: I totally understood what you said, it works now